# Problem with the selenium options in c# options.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=/local");

Tags: c#

i got a problem while creating a Webscraper with c#

in order to bypass logins and captchaes i would have to use cookies to load my data, i found out today that i can use a argument in the WebDriver Options which saves and loads a chrome profile i can use for selenium.

```
options.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=./local");
```

this is the argument i am using

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"chromedriver.exe", options);
```

and this how i start the driver, however the rest of my code doesnt get executed but at the same time my program doesnt crash and just seems in an idle mode.

when i delete this option everything works just fine and the rest of my code gets executed..

this is the entire startup code in case that helps:

```
            options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
            options.AddArguments("--disable-logging");
            options.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=./local");

            if (settings.Contains("vpn"))
            {
                options.AddExtension("vpn.crx");
            }

            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"chromedriver.exe", options);
```